# How to get output from custom component in slickgrid?

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I have ionic application and using the custom component in slickgrid. I can give input to my component from slickgrid. But I didn't receive my output emit from my component to slickgrid.

```
 renderAngularComponent(cellNode: HTMLElement, row: number, dataContext: any, colDef: Column) {
    if (colDef.params.component) {
        const componentOutput = this.angularUtilService.createAngularComponent(colDef.params.component);
        Object.assign(componentOutput.componentRef.instance, { selectedItem: dataContext, a: this.a, b: this.b });
        setTimeout(() => $(cellNode).empty().html(componentOutput.domElement));
    }
}
```

I called the above mentioned method in the column definition by this way

```
asyncPostRender: this.renderAngularComponent.bind(this)
```

This is all about to providing input to the component.please guide the way to receive the output or callback in the slickgrid component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentOutput.componentRef.instance` holds the component instance, so you just have to attach the output property manually, for example if there is `save`

```
componentOutput.componentRef.instance.save.subscribe(()=>{console.log("method called");
```